# Should I return callback from Node.js Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm wondering whether the return is required at the end of this example Express function. I've seen many examples where the return isn't included and some where it is. (I'm also not sure why the result is converted to string and then back to JSON, but that's a different question.)

```
/**
 * @param {string} id
 * @param {function} callback 
 */
function getPersonCount (id, callback) {
  connection.query('SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM people WHERE id=?;', [id], function(err, result) {
    var string = JSON.stringify(result);
    var json =  JSON.parse(string);
    var count = json[0].count;
    callback(count);
    return callback;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear: You're returning `callback` from the anonymous callback you're passing into `query`.

TL;DR No, you almost certainly don't want to return it, though it's probably harmless if you do.

---

It has nothing to do with Express, it has to do with that `query` function. If it expects the callback you give it to return a function that it will do something with, then you should return an appropriate function (whether `callback` is that function is a question, and I suspect the answer would be no, but...). If not, no, you shouldn't.

I'd say the odds are **extremely** high that `query` completely ignores the return value of the callback you're passing it.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to note that in many instances where `return` is used within the context of callbacks, it may also be used for explicit termination of the executing context to prevent any subsequent synchronous code from being invoked. While this isn't required in some instances the lack/inclusion of a `return` could change the behavior of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to return your callback example :

```
function getPersonCount (id, callback) {
  connection.query('SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM people WHERE id=?;', [id], function(err, result) {
    var string = JSON.stringify(result);
    var json =  JSON.parse(string);
    var count = json[0].count;
    callback(count);
  });
}
```

To use this function you have to do something like this :

```
getPersonCount (id, function(result){
   //here you can use the data from your function
   console.log(result)
})
```